# RaphaelJS: Make a line that is solid at the center and has a transparent "border"

Tags: svg, raphael

In RaphaelJS I'm using the path function to draw a black line. This line is draggable, but because of its' width it is hard to drag on a tablet. What I's like to do is fill around the line with a transparent "border". This way the line wouldn't look any wider, but there would be more area to grab on to on a tablet device. Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Here's an example of how I'm drawing a line:

```
paper.path("M 150 250 h 200").attr({
fill: "#ff0",
gradient: "90-#526c7a-#64a0c1",
stroke: "#3b4449",
"stroke-width": 5
});
```

Comment: What about making stroke same color as your canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may depend a bit on if its going over some other objects etc. If the other solution doesn't work, you could try grouping 2 objects into a set, and have one as the trigger point. So like the following...

```
var set = r.set();
var rect = r.rect(200,200,50,70).attr({ fill: 'red' });

set.push(
   r.path("M 150 250 h 200").attr({
    fill: "#ff0",
    gradient: "90-#526c7a-#64a0c1",
    stroke: "#3b4449",
    "stroke-width": 5
    })
    );
set.push( 
  r.path("M 150 250 h 200").attr({
    fill: "#ff0",
    gradient: "90-#526c7a-#64a0c1",
    stroke: "#3b4449",
    "stroke-width": 20,
    "stroke-opacity": 0.05,
    "stroke-linecap": "round"
    })
);

set.mouseover(function(){
alert('mouse over');
});
```

There is a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Ap29U/2/ showing it over another object (the opacity could be adjusted further, 0.01 would probably make it pretty much invisble). I've also just added a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Ap29U/3/ showing how you could make them both move together.